# Best way to deploy an assembly to the GAC on a build machine

Tags: automated-tests, gac

Our unit tests expect to find a certain assembly in the GAC. I am wondering what is the best way to put the assembly in the GAC on the build server that is part of TFS2010 automated build?
Is it a good idea to use a post build event with gacutil /i?
Are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your unit tests expect the DLL in the GAC or just available to .NET assembly probing?  If it's actually the latter, why don't you use [DeploymentItem()] attributes and have the assembly copied to the test folder and then found by .NET via probing?  Another option would be to use a HintPath in your test DLL's config file.